# What are the cognate patterns for adjectives in French?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs

I'm reading "French for Reading" by Sandberg and there is a section for cognate patterns for adjectives that I do not understand on page 4:

[image: Page 4 from French for Reading]

There are four items here that I'd like to clarify

1. Sandberg states that `-en` and `-euse` in French often correspond to `-ous` in English.  Should this be `-eux` and `-euse` in French correspond to `-ous` in English?
2. He also states that `-eux` and `-elle` in French often correspond to `-al` in English.  Should this be `-el` and `-elle` in French correspond to `-al` in English?
3. Next, he states that `-el` and `-ive` in French usually correspond to `-ive` in English.  Should this be `-if` and `-ive` in French usually correspond to `-ive` in English?
4. Finally, he states that `-if` and `-enne` in French often correspond
   to `-an` in English.  Should this be `-en` and `-enne` in French
   often correspond to `-an` in English?

Comment: As a side note I would be very suspicious about this book, seeing that many mistakes on a single page... or at least what I consider mistakes as I fully agree with your corrections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your corrections are  right.

- 1/ **eux**, euse (**ous**) — vicieux/vicieuse (vicious), pieux/pieuse (pious), précieux/précieuse (precious), sérieux/sérieuse (serious), bulbeux/bulbeuse (bulbous)
- 2/ **el**, elle (**al**) — officiel/officielle (official), constitutionnel/constitutionnelle (constitutional), réel/réelle (real)
- 3/ **if**, ive (**ive**) — consécutif/consécutive (consecutive), abrasif/abrasive (abrasive), abusif/abusive (abusive), constructif/constructive (constructive), conclusif/conclusive (conclusive)
- 4/ **en**, enne (**an**) — autrichien/autrichienne (Austrian), canadien/canadienne (Canadian), martien/martienne (Martian), diététicien/diététicienne (dietician), méditerranéen/méditerranéenne (mediterranean),  mathématicien/mathématicienne (mathematician), parisien/parisienne (Parisian), londonien/londonienne (Londonian)